# How to include PHPmailer in functions.php properly (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to include PHPmailer in functions.php

my code:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test_mailer', 'test_mailer');
```

function test_mailer () {

```
try {

    require_once(get_template_directory('/includes/mail/PHPMailer.php'));
    require_once(get_template_directory('/includes/mail/Exception.php'));

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions

    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'test@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'dummypassword!';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('test@gmail.com', 'Mailer Test');
    $mail->addAddress('john.doe@gmail.com', 'John User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('test@gmail.com');

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject testing';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

wp_die();
```

}

I also tried to put require_once out of the try catch still the same error here is the snippet about the error

> "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found"

I use betheme template and I stored the files PHPmailer in betheme/includes/mail.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the built in wp_mail functions? They already use PHPMailer. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init

Comment: Hey @BA_Webimax great info cheers What I'm trying to do is send user data through ajax and if success inside functions.php (my_function) I grab the user email and send an confirmation email to user and save the fields (user inputs) in my table and I don't want to reload the entire page when user submit the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As BA_Webimax pointed out, you should be using Wordpress' built-in email functions, though due to WP's reliance on outdated PHP versions, you will end up using a very old version of PHPMailer with it.

Back to your current problem: It's not your `require_once` statements that are failing, it's that you have not imported the namespaced PHPMailer classes into your namespace. Add these at the top of your script:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
```

Alternatively, use the FQCN when creating your instance:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

Note that this applies to the `Exception` class too, so you'd need to say:

```
catch (PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception $e) {
```

Comment: Hey Synchro I tried to follow your suggestion but I still get an error
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer' not found

Comment: I tried to put $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; inside and outside the try catch but still the same maybe its wrong to put the PHPmailer in this directory betheme/includes/mail

Comment: I only include PHPMailer.php, Exception and SMTP.php maybe I missed something to include?

Comment: If you are successfully loading the class file and are declaring the FQCN one way or another, I don’t see how this is failing. Perhaps the files you’re loading do not actually contain the PHPMailer classes?

Answer (score 1):

`get_template_directory()` returns the absolute path of the theme and doesn't take any params.

Try this for your includes:

```
require_once(get_template_directory().'/includes/mail/PHPMailer.php');
require_once(get_template_directory().'/includes/mail/Exception.php');
```